SFINAE way to conditionally declare and define a member function
I have a file logger like this:
struct file_logger{
    logger &__logger;
    const int32_t __log_fd;
    friend class logger;
    template <severity sev, typename... Args>
    inline void log(Args... args);
    template <severity sev, char sep, typename... Args>
    inline void log_s(int32_t log_fd, Args... args);
private:
    file_logger(logger &l, const int32_t &fd) : __logger(l), __log_fd(fd) {}
};
template <severity sev, typename... Args>
inline void file_logger::log(Args... args){
    __logger.log<sev>(__log_fd, args...);
}
template <severity sev, char sep, typename... Args>
inline void file_logger::log_s(int32_t log_fd, Args... args){
    __logger.log_s<sev, sep>(__log_fd, args...);
}

I would like to have special member like info for instance which will log for a specific severity. I want this because it is frustrating to write log<severity::INFO> everytime I want to use log some info.
so I can have
/*assume info declared in file_logger*/
template<typename... Args>
inline void file_logger::info(Args... args){
__logger.log<severity::INFO>(args...);
}

So I have decided to add some common severities like info,warn,error,debug. However, I also want to have a compile time check that the severity level exists in the enum for which the function is defined. In case the severity is not defined. I want to have a compilation error if and only if the function is called. Otherwise, I would like the compiler to ignore the template.
I am using c++17.

So there can be different severity enums, the user can specify their own?

std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function and C++ templates: conditionally enabled member function

@HolyBlackCat for severities like CRITICAL, TRACE etc., I don't need such members as they are used more rarely. If they are used anywhere and are not part of the severity enum, the compiler will raise error. I want the same for the special functions except that the .h should not need to be edited to remove info for example if info is not compilable. in case info is used, the compiler should raise error. but if info is not used and info is not compilable, the compiler should ignore.
